# Inserting in Excel sheet from another Excel sheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am trying to read one excel sheet and then creating another excel sheet through OleDb

In this another excel sheet, I made some colums like Name char(10), Age Number

now when I reading that excel sheet and trying to insert the values in this another excel sheet then values are inserting but also contains one extra char i.e single quote(') as the first char.

Why all the values are instered with single quote pre to actual value? How to get rid of it? I am using c#.net for this.

@Edit

```
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                   cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                   cmd.Connection = con;
                   cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Data1 (Name char(10), Age char(10)) ";

                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

foreach (DataRow row in someDataTable.Rows)
 {

       cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Data1 values ('" + row["Name"] +
                       "','" + row["Age"] +  "')";

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I have exactlly the same data in someDataTable as in excel which I need to copy.

Comment: I need more information to find an answer, please post some example code.

Comment: I have given some code also,....

Comment: I can't find any error in your code. Try stepping through it in the debugger. For a first attempt, set your `CommandText` to `"INSERT INTO Data1 values ('Bart Simpson','12')";`. If the error is gone, the cause is somewhere in the building of your query. If it isn't, it is in the SQL syntax.

Comment: it is inserting the values but those values contain single quote prefixed to them. Code has no error

Comment: It's the single quote that is confusing me - I would expect there to be both (leading and trailing) quotes, or none at all...

Comment: I checked the values which I am trying to insert. They doesn't conatin any quote in it but when I open the excel sheet it shows the values prefixed with single quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be strange, but maybe it is some sort of attempt of OleDb to avoid SQL Injection? (What if `row["Name"]` contains a single quote?) Even if it does not explain, like @Treb said, why there is a leading quote only, without a trailing one.

What happens if you try to use the query with parameters, ie.:

```
using (OleDbCommand addLine = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Data1 values (@name, @age)"))
{
    addLine.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", row["Name"]);
    addLine.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", row["Age"]);
    int affectedRows = addLine.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Debug.Assert(1 == affectedRows);
}
```

---

After a few attempts, I still can't reproduce the observed behavior. I suggest to do several things:

- Post in your question the whole source code which produces the single quote problem,
- Try the following source (Console application) and see what happens. In my case, values are inserted well, without any leading single quotes. The only problem are the ages, inserted as text instead of numbers (which can probably be solved by explicitly specifying the type of the row):

Source code:

```
namespace Demos.StackOverflow.ExcelUpdate
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Data.OleDb;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // -> Change the following name of the file to use.
            string fullPath = @"C:\Users\Arsene\Desktop\Book1.xlsx";
            string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0'", fullPath);

            Collection<Tuple<string, int>> dataToPut = new Collection<Tuple<string, int>>();

            dataToPut.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Some name", 34));
            dataToPut.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Other name here", 41));
            dataToPut.Add(new Tuple<string, int>("Last one", 36));

            using (OleDbConnection oleConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                oleConnection.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand createTable = new OleDbCommand("create table Data1 (Name char(10), Age char(10))", oleConnection))
                {
                    createTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                foreach (var t in dataToPut)
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand addItem = new OleDbCommand("insert into Data1 values (@name, @age)", oleConnection))
                    {
                        addItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", t.Item1);
                        addItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", t.Item2);
                        addItem.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked through debugging row["Name"] it contains the value only, without any quote but on inserting it shows signle quote in value in that excel

Comment: @Nits: I know. In all cases, you tried the suggestion of @Treb in the third comment to the question, and it didn't work, when it should. Well, try with parameters and see if it works.

Comment: even though fields name also have single quote prefixed. Like 'Name  and  'Age

Comment: it is still givign me the same single quote pre to each value, it also didn't work

Comment: Although problem with the single quote is not solved but when I tried to Import the excel sheet in oracle it didn't give any error and took those values without that single quote.

Comment: @Nits: well, if the source code I posted in my edit still produces single quote problem for you, there is probably something wrong with your Microsoft Office installation. Try on other PCs, then try to reinstall Microsoft Office to see if it works. You can also report the bug to Microsoft Connect.

Comment: I'll give a try on another PC also and will post a update in the same concern but if the values are having single quote pre to each value then why while importing it is taking the correct value automatically? this is a question in my head. Also is the Excel error or it is oracle's, i.e also not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem, inserted fields would get a leading single quote. I've found out that this was only the case when using the JET 4.0 library, the moment I switched to the ACE 12.0 library, the problem was solved.